# Create custom service in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, services, trac

How do you run a custom service in Windows 7?
Does anyone know how to setup [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindowsStandalone) as a custom service in Windows 7?

Answer (score 11):

The link you have provided also points towards [Trac On Windows](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows) [link is now bad], which seems a pretty complete description of the installation process.

In section 3 I find the following line:

```
sc create svnserver binpath="C:\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svnrepositories" displayname= "Subversion Server (svnserver)" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

which creates a system service. However, I don't know if that's the service you need.

Answer (score 1):

yep srvany seems to be only way - unless someone else knows another way using

"sc create /?" in cmd prompt (i dont)

Comment: i think the service being request is "Running Tracd as service" - not sure how to run this as a service on windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If you're scared by the command line and not scared to spend money, then [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/) allows you to easily set up services.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SrvAny](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) from the Windows NT Resource Kit.