# How to stop programs from ever running again?

Tags: windows-7

System: Windows 7 64-bit

I need to stop programs from running, or ever running again. If I try to start the program, it'll be corrupted and unable to start.

How can I corrupt the program? Do I mess with the registry? The Program files?

edit: how about deleting the .dll's inside of the programs folder?

Comment: Can you just delete the program, or some critical component of it?

Comment: do you want to prevent SOME programs to run or ALL programs to run?

Comment: It seems like there are lots of possible ways to accomplish this. Perhaps there is some additional detail you can provide?

Comment: I want to stop SOME programs from RUNNING ever again. maybe remove a component or whatever.

Comment: The real answer depends on which programs.

Comment: anti viruses, etc

Comment: are you an user with administrator privileges?

Comment: @kb67  and they could run a portable equivalent program from a USB stick.

Comment: If it were antivirus, why don't you just disable it in services or uninstall it? Why go though this crap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent these executables from starting up?](http://superuser.com/questions/253188/how-to-prevent-these-executables-from-starting-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the executable file, it will be called `something.exe`, if you rename it to `something.bak` the operating system will not be able to execute it as an application. It will only be able to be run if it is renamed back to `something.exe`.

Comment: Technically, this answer is incorrect – while you won't be able to execute a non-`.exe` file from GUI, you can do it just fine from Command Prompt (*cmd.exe*) or through any other program that uses `CreateProcess()`. *(Memories of hiding a SSH client in Desktop.ini at school...)*

Comment: This also assumes the program is an executable.

Comment: Considering he said in his comment above he wants to disable AV, this is not even remotely a good way to do it.

Comment: @KCotreau, it's a perfectly cromulent way, any program, even AV will not run if the OS can't find the executable.

Comment: @nnewton Geeze, thank for the lesson on the OS not running the AV if it can't find the executable...I somehow missed that lesson in 17 years as an IT pro...NO KIDDING. Considering you can just disable the service, or if it is in the Run registries, use MSCONFIG to disable it, I stand by my comment: It is an IDIOTIC way to do it. Your computer will still try to start it, and error out.

Answer (score 7):

well, you can use security options for that EXE or for its folder and uncheck "read and execute" for all users.

Comment: does only "REEAD ONLY" work

Comment: No.  Read only still allows access to and execution of the files.  You need to actually change the permissions on the files so that all access is denied; use the Security tab on the Properties page of the files in question.

Comment: This is a good way, one can actually restrict permission from the program's folder itself.

Answer (score 5):

Open the .exe file in notepad and just add few characters here and there before saving again.  Program busted.

Comment: Haha great idea!

Comment: Note that standard Windows notepad enforces the line end characters to be CRLF, so after doing this the program won't be recoverable!

Answer (score 2):

There's no hard and fast way to totally disable a program  - every program is different, and in any case, reinstalling it probably 'fix' whatever you did to disable it.

On the other hand you COULD set up the computer as you like it, and use a standard account (disabling what you don't want with autoruns )and use ['guest mode'](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/windows-7-feature-focus-guest-mode) to prevent changes from happening. You can also remove execute privileges to the folders with the software you want (rightclock, properties, security tab), to this account.

Unlike messing with things at a low level, should you need to undo these changes, it should be trivial, and a guest moded user account will be able to do almost nothing.